# Wrap/close 'query' for a first-letter ordered listing of posts

Tags: query

Sorry for the title, I didn’t know how to call it better.

I am working on a site on which I am building a listing of doctors being ordered alphabetically by last name/word of title, while all posts belonging to a letter should be grouped together below it, just like this:

> **A**
>
> - Dr. John Arbuckle
> - Dr. Mack Ancie
>
> **B**
>
> - Dr. Howie B.
> - Dr. Bones

The listing is fine, only I cannot get a div to wrap around each letter’s block enclosing the letter and its posts. The desired output for one block should be

```
<div class="letter_item">
  <h2>A</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link">Dr. John Arbuckle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link">Dr. Mack Ancie</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So far, since I cannot properly close it, the lists are cascading (see live example link). 
The code I use is the following, and since it checks for the first letter and inserts the h2 only when a different letter is used, it cannot be used to wrap the code for the list.

```
<div class="section_index grid_12 section_aerzte" id="aerzte">
  <?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'arzt',
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );

    function mam_posts_orderby ($orderby) {
    global $mam_global_orderby;
    if ($mam_global_orderby) $orderby = $mam_global_orderby;
    return $orderby;
    }
    add_filter('posts_orderby','mam_posts_orderby');
    $mam_global_orderby = "
    UPPER(CONCAT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE($wpdb->posts.post_title),' ',1)),$wpdb->posts.post_title))
    ";

    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) {
      $curr_letter = '';
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        $fullposttile = "$post->post_title";
        $words = explode(' ', $fullposttile);
        $lastWord = array_pop($words);

        $this_letter = strtoupper(substr($lastWord,0,1));
        if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {
          echo "<div class='letter_item'><h2>$this_letter</h2><ul>";
          $curr_letter = $this_letter;
        }
?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>

  <?php }
}
?>
/** Here it goes wrong, obviously **/
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

If it helps, the live example of the test site is at http://www.physalis-web.com/aerztegemeinschaft/aerzte . Is there a (better) way to get a wrapping properly done? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each time you start a new letter, you don't close the list of the previous one.

Inside your check `if ($this_letter != $curr_letter)`, before the `echo`, you have to add a `</ul>` in all cases except when `$curr_letter` is empty (the first letter).

```
if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {
    if('' != $curr_letter){
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
    echo "<div class='letter_item'><h2>$this_letter</h2><ul>";
    $curr_letter = $this_letter;
}
```

Comment: Quite exactly, but how would I actually do that :D? And it would need to close the div as well, of course.

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Hey there, I thought it must produce a problem with a left-over `</ul></div>`, but it’s actually fine and well-working. Thanks a lot, you nailed it!